# How to remove the circular dependency from this use of the Strategy pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to grok the Strategy pattern and came up with the following example:

- I'd like to create new games based on chess except with pieces that move differently.
- I also want to use the Strategy pattern to inject behaviors (how they can move) into the pieces.

But if we have `Board`, `Piece`, and `MoveBehavior` objects

- `Board` -> `Piece` because a `Board` contains `Piece`s
- `Piece` -> `Board` because a piece needs to pass in the `Board` as a param to

  - `MoveBehavior` which needs the `Board` to decide what moves are acceptable.

How can we get rid of this circular dependency? Also, isn't this a common problem in more realistic examples because behaviors need large enough state to make decisions? I think if the behavior is super simple it's not that big a deal to not use the Strategy pattern.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you can use a dependency injection framework to resolve all the object instances. You will need a configurable container if you want to use different combinations of types to instantiate. You could call the configurable container a strategy (as it selects all the pieces that come into play).

I would not make the board responsible for creating all the pieces and behaviors, but rather use a composer class (that uses dependency injection) for that.

This allows you (for example) to use behaviors for the board, or to create different board types as well.

See also [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085922/62662) for some background on how dependency injection helps to obtain loose coupling.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use `Board` -> `Piece` -> `MoveBehaviour`.

The reason being is that the board contains the pieces and the pieces have their own move behaviour depending on what type they are.

`MoveBehaviour` tells the piece its allowed movements i.e. (example is C# because that is what I am familiar with)

```
public Move[] Moves
{
    get
    {
        return new Move[] { Move.Horizontal, Move.Vertical };
    }
}
```

The job of `MoveBehaviour` is not to see if the `Piece` can move to where it is requesting that is the board.

More easily explained in the below C# example:

```
public class Board
{
    public List<Piece> Pieces { get; set; }

    public bool CanMoveTo(Piece piece, Point location) { /*...*/ }
}

public class Piece : IMoveBehaviour
{
    public Move[] Moves { get; set; }
}

public interface IMoveBehaviour
{
    Move[] moves { get; set; }
}
```

And with methods in `Board` and `Piece` like `RequestMove`, `Move`, `IsValidMove` etc...

Essentially leave the responsibility of something to that something and do not move it around. `MoveBehaviour` is the behaviour of a `Piece` not the validation of the moves that is the `Board`s responsibility.